# Android Fused Location Provider API Not Returning Correct Address Everytime

Tags: android, android-asynctask, location, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am a beginner in Android and I am building a location based app using Fused Location Provider Api. The application takes the coordinates and uses reverse geocoding to get the exact address which is needed for later use.But the problem is that it returns both Latitude and Longitude as 0 sometimes.Also most times it fails to get the exact address as if it fails to call the asyncTask class.Please help as I cant think of any solution to it.  I am posting my code below.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private String LOG_STRING="Connection";
    private  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Location mlocation;
    LocationManager location;
    double Latitude,Longitude;
    private Button messageSend;
    Intent in;
    boolean isGpsOn;
    DBAction dbcheck=new DBAction(MainActivity.this);


    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        messageSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
        location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Checking for Google Play Services
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if(status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Google Play Services Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }

        messageSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isGpsOn=location.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (dbcheck.isDBEmpty())
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Contacts Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if(!isGpsOn)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is off!!Please turn it On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent GPSIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(GPSIntent);
                }
                else {

                    AsyncTry obj = new AsyncTry(getBaseContext());
                    obj.execute();
                }

            }
        });


    }



    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest= LocationRequest.create();
       mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);


        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

       // mlocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

//          if(mlocation!=null) {
//              Latitude = mlocation.getLatitude();
//              Longitude = mlocation.getLongitude();
//          }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(LOG_STRING,"Connetion Suspended");


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(LOG_STRING,"Connection Failed");

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mlocation=location;
        if(location!=null) {
            Latitude = mlocation.getLatitude();
            Longitude = mlocation.getLongitude();
        }


    }




    public void sendMessage(String add)
    {  List<DBAction> arrylist=new ArrayList<DBAction>();
        arrylist=dbcheck.readFromDB();
        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        for(DBAction db:arrylist)
            sm.sendTextMessage(db.cNumber, null, add, null, null);
    }


    public class AsyncTry extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
        Context context;
        String add;
        ProgressDialog pd;


        public AsyncTry(Context context) {

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude,Longitude, 1);
                    if (addresses != null)
                    {
                        Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                        for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                        {
                            str.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                        }

                    }

                }
                add=str.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception:", e.toString());
            }
            finally {
                if(add!=null)
                    add="Latitude:"+Latitude+"\nLongitude:"+Longitude+"\n"+add;
                else
                    add="Latitude:"+Latitude+"\nLongitude:"+Longitude+"\nCant Find Address for this location";
            }

            return add;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Getting Location...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();

            if (result != null) {

              sendMessage(result);
                Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

@p.matthew13 according to this document [*Getting the Last Known Location*](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

> In order for the fused location provider to retrieve a precise street address, set the location permission in your app manifest to *ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION*, as shown in the following example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Another fact:

> The priority of *PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY*, combined with the *ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION* permission setting that you've defined in the app manifest, and a fast update interval of 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds), causes the fused location provider to return location updates that are accurate to within a few feet. This approach is appropriate for mapping apps that display the location in real time.

And a sample code for getting the location:

```
private void updateUI() {
mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
}
```

Kindly review this document [Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), I can't pinpoint to where your mistake because the API is working just need a little code revision. Use that guide to back track on your codes and compare if you have followed the same step/procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I had already set the permission to FINE_LOCATION as well as COARSE_LOCATION with a time interval of 10 secs.Let me check the your suggestions